# Basic Slider: Place caption under image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-slider

I need to show image slide show for news which can have one or more than one image displayed.

If it has just one image then Navigation bar should hide, This feature is built in.

But i am facing problem with moving the caption of the image exactly under the Image. I am able to change the bottom margin for css `p.bjqs-caption` to -30px. which moves the caption but hides under something and is not visible i tried all options like `z-index` and other stuff but nothing seem to work.

I would appreciate help in this regard.

Slider : http://www.basic-slider.com/

I tried to setup fiddle but demo on fiddle is not working link http://jsfiddle.net/rUXAt/1/

UPDATE : Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rUXAt/2/

Comment: fiddle working now check http://jsfiddle.net/rUXAt/2/

Comment: @SridharR, Thanks i am not able to figure out what was wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one,
put height for ul and li  **height: 355px !important;** and **color to p.bjqs-caption**

```
p.bjqs-caption {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;
}
p.bjqs-caption {
    bottom: 0;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 96%;
}

ul.bjqs {
    display: none;
    height: 355px !important;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

li.bjqs-slide {
    display: none;
    height: 355px !important;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check working fiddle

```
p.bjqs-caption {
    bottom: 0;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 96%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rUXAt/2/